# Is there a way to use colour in ColorScheme in other ThemeData?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

const ColorScheme colorScheme = ColorScheme(
  primary: Color.fromRGBO(48, 48, 48, 1),
  primaryVariant: Color.fromRGBO(38, 38, 38, 1),
  onPrimary: Colors.white,
  secondary: Color.fromRGBO(232, 163, 72, 1),
  secondaryVariant: Color.fromRGBO(168, 121, 59, 1),
  onSecondary: Colors.white,
  surface: Colors.white,
  onSurface: Color.fromRGBO(48, 48, 48, 1),
  background: Colors.white,
  onBackground: Color.fromRGBO(48, 48, 48, 1),
  error: Color.fromRGBO(214, 84, 84, 1),
  onError: Colors.white,
  brightness: Brightness.light,
);

const FloatingActionButtonThemeData fabTheme = FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
  
);
```

I am creating a separate `theme.dart` file for themes and wish to keep all the themes in that file.

Here, I want to use colors in `ColorScheme` in `FloatingActionButtonThemeData`. I am aware of the fact that I can use ColorScheme only in the context whose ancestor has this scheme. But is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    colorScheme: colorScheme,
    floatingActionButtonTheme: fabTheme,
   // or Theme.of(context).floatingActionButtonTheme.copyWith(...),
  ),
  ....
```

For specific widget, wrap with `Theme` widget and provide theme

```dart
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    colorScheme: colorScheme,
    floatingActionButtonTheme: fabTheme,
  ),
  child: ...
```

More about [themes](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes) and I'm following [extending-the-parent-theme](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes#extending-the-parent-theme) which seems better option.